# Android SQLite turkish language

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on an Android application which supports both **English** and **Turkish** Language.
The app contains **SQLite** database which contains a Table and **Autoincrement _id** column.

When this app runs on English device it works fine, but when running it on **Turkish** device the database stops generating ids automatically.

I have tried to extract the database file and open it on SQLite Database Browser, it is saving all columns values correctly, only **_id** column's value still empty in **Turkish** Locale

Ideas to solve this issue?

**Edit:**

Creating Database:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final static String TAG = "DatabaseHandler";

    private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "app_main_database";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE tbl_item (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NULL, _serverId TEXT NULL, _itemName TEXT NULL, _lastEditDate DATETIME NOT NULL)";

        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

Insert Row to the Table:

```
    @Override
    public void insert() {
        ContentValues reVal = new ContentValues();

        reVal.put(COL_ITEM_SERVER_ID, getItemServerId());
        reVal.put(COL_ITEM_NAME, getItemName());
        reVal.put(COL_LAST_EDIT_DATE, getLastEditDate());

        SQLiteDatabase sqLite = new DatabaseHandler(this).getWritableDatabase();
        sqLite.insert(tableName, null, obj.getContentValues());
    }
```

Comment: How do you populate your database? If you create it on android it should be UTF-8 by default. If you are loading it from a text file make sure that the text is UTF-8 encoded

Comment: No, I am creating it on android using `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: `_id column's value still empty` how do you observe this ?

Comment: By extracting the database and opening it in sqlite broser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to open your database and set locale (using [`setLocale`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setLocale%28java.util.Locale%29)) to english. By default it will use the system locale.

Using [`openDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29) you can set [`NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS) flag too (which disables every setLocale and could fix your problem (but never tested it just some research right now))

```
public static final int NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS

Added in API level 1
Open flag: Flag for openDatabase(String, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory, int) to open the database without support for localized collators.

This causes the collator LOCALIZED not to be created. You must be consistent when using this flag to use the setting the database was created with. If this is set, setLocale(Locale) will do nothing.

Constant Value: 16 (0x00000010)
```

As first try, i would test the `setLocale` on `datatabase` object.